# SpringBoot native image limitations

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

If you need to provide everything at build time.
Would that also imply that you cannot use `@Value` annotation, configure datasource bean with credentials provided at runtime/startup time via environment variables?
To be more specific let's say you have application.properties and there `spring.datasource.username=${ADMIN_USERNAME}`. Do you need to provide password at build time and it will be baked into native image?
The same goes for configuration class e.g.

```
@Configuration 
public class ShoesConfig{
   @Value("{shoes.size}")
   private Integer size;
}
```

which you would also provide via env variable at app startup. Do you know the answer?